# C# inserting <input> in htmldocument

Tags: c#, input, insert, dom

How do I insert a `<input type="text" ...>` in a `Systems.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htmlelement to create a input type tag

```
HtmlElement input = doc.CreateElement("input");
```

Refer this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx#Y300
gives an example on how you could do it but that will become a maintenance nightmare after a while.

might be beter to use the createElement - method that can be found here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx